# Create Exclusive OR constraint across two columns

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have a table with two columns (amongst others):

```
NotApplicable  bit
TargetLevel    numeric(5,2)
```

I need to create a constraint whereby the following rules apply:

1. NotApplicable and TargetLevel cannot both be NULL
2. NotApplicable and TargetLevel cannot both have values
3. NotApplicable or TargetLevel must have a value

I guess this is an exclusive OR scenario?  I had a go a while back, but I realised now that this doesn't account for the last scenario above:

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[my_Table] ADD CONSTRAINT [DF_tbl_my_Table_notApplicable] DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [notApplicable]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[my_Table] WITH CHECK ADD CONSTRAINT [CK_tbl_my_Table] CHECK  ((COALESCE([targetLevel],[notapplicable]) IS NOT NULL))
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[my_Table] CHECK CONSTRAINT [CK_tbl_my_Table]
GO
```

Any help perfecting this would be appreciated.  Also, is the last ALTER statement actually needed in the example above please?

Comment: Why do you need a separate `NotApplicable` column? It could be implied that if `TargetLevel IS NULL` it is not applicable.

Comment: @EvilDr It's recommended to name things in their positive form. It's hard to read double negatives. SQL: `NotApplicable <> 1`  C#: `!NotApplicable` VB: `Not NotApplicable`

Comment: Hi.  Yes normally I would follow this, but its part of a much larger set of rules whereby a small number of rows need to be hidden after a large search.  Thank you.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's a bit verbose, but the standard way I do it is just:

```
ALTER TABLE T ADD CONSTRAINT CK_One_Or_Tother CHECK (
    (NotApplicable IS NULL and TargetLevel IS NOT NULL) OR
    (NotApplicable IS NOT NULL and TargetLevel IS NULL)
)
```

---

> Also, is the last ALTER statement actually needed in the example above please?

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[my_Table] CHECK CONSTRAINT [CK_tbl_my_Table]
```

This is only necessary if you have ever created or altered the constraint and specified `NOCHECK`, or have in some other way disabled the constraint previously and now enabled it. The default for creation of constraints is for them to be enabled.

---

For a large number of columns, for which exactly one must be filled in, I tend to switch to an alternative structure:

```
ALTER TABLE T ADD CONSTRAINT CK_One_Or_Tother CHECK (
    1 = (
        CASE WHEN ColumnA IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +
        CASE WHEN ColumnB IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +
        CASE WHEN ColumnC IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +
        CASE WHEN ColumnD IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
    )
)
```

Which has the advantage of only naming each column once, but can look a bit ugly.

Comment: "One_Or_Tother" as in the Yorkshire T'Other?!!?

Comment: @EvilDr - Yep. Just feeling in that kind of mood today.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative syntax for the two column scenario is:

```
ALTER TABLE T ADD CONSTRAINT CK_One_Or_Tother CHECK (
     (NotApplicable IS NULL     OR TargetLevel IS NULL)
 AND (NotApplicable IS NOT NULL OR TargetLevel IS NOT NULL)
)
```